# vuejs not update component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I click on links, `mounted()` works, but new template not loading from server, vue not send AJAX request if route is changed.

```html
<section class="content">
    <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
</section>

<router-link to="/foo"></router-link>
<router-link to="/bar"></router-link>
<router-link to="/somelink"></router-link>
```

```js
var testComponent = Vue.component('main-section', (resolve) => {
    axios.post('/test.php').then( (res) => {
        resolve({ 
            template: res.data,
            mounted: () => {
                console.log('mounted-' + new Date().getTime());
            }
        });
    });
});

var router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
    { path: '/foo', component: testComponent }, 
    { path: '/bar', component: testComponent },
    { path: '*', component: testComponent }],
    mode: 'history'
});
```

Comment: What do you want to achive?

Answer (score 0):

Your component is the same for all of your routes, so Vue will load `testComponent` only one time. Once it has loaded a component, Vue will never reload it again.

Comment: And no way to force vue for reload?

Comment: You can do your request in the vue component mounted hook and display result in the template. But I should say that you rendering approach is very strange :/ It's looks like server side rendering, but with a single page applications (which doesn't make sense)

Comment: I think you can define individual compent like “testComponent1, testComponent2.." for different route to make it.